# Attaching an event from an unreferenced library

Tags: c#, circular-dependency

I need to fire a method in library b, when a method is called in library a.

For example, is it somehow possible for `library b` to attach  to the event `testEvent` in library a?

**library a - cannot reference library b (because of a circular dependency)**

```
public event testEvent = null;
pubic class alpha{
   public void main(){//application entry point       
   }
}
```

**library b - has reference to `library a`**

```
public class beta{
  public void hello(){
  }
}
```

Failing that, I think I will have to create a third library, `library c`, that has a reference to `library b`, and is referenced by `library a`.

Comment: Can you initialize beta some where and put reference to alpha?

Comment: Can you make interface in library A and use them in B?

Comment: Can you use DI container and initialize beta as module wich resolve alpha and subscribe testEvent? Or resolve beta from alpha (by interface) and call hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest solutions would be to have an interface definition in a and the implementation in b. Then, in a, you resolve the reference to an instance of the interface with reflection:

B.dll:

```
 public class beta : ibeta {
    public void hello() {
    }
 }
```

A.dll:

```
 public interface ibeta {
    void hello();
 }

 ..

 public static void Main()
 {
     // resolve type by its fully qualified name
     ibeta b = (ibeta)Activator.CreateInstance( Type.GetType( "beta, B" ) );
     b.hello(); 
 }
```